# How to convert $X \lor (Y \land (X \lor Z))$ to CNF?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Im having difficulty expanding $X \lor (Y \land (X \lor Z))$
 to CNF. Looked up the distributive law formulas, but got stuck on:

$$X \lor ((Y \land X) \lor (Y \land Z))$$

How do I complete the last step and convert to CNF?

Answer (score 3):

What you will end up with with that approach is the DNF instead:

$$X\lor(Y\land X)\lor(Y\land Z)$$

So you'd have to use the outer instead for the distributive law (ie $A\lor(B\land C) = (A\lor B)\land(A\lor C)$:

$$X\lor(Y\land(X\lor Z)) = (X\lor Y)\land(X\lor (X\lor Z)) \\
 (X\lor Y)\land (X\lor Z)$$